# Json.NET: Does the $type variable (when using TypeNameHandling) require the "qualified type name"?

Tags: android, json, jackson, json.net

I have a C#-server using Json.NET and on the other side a JAVA/Android-app using Jackson.

I serialize and deserialize an object called ProtocolContainer, and that object contains among other things one property called "SubPacket":

```
public class ProtocolContainer
{
    public DataPacket SubPacket { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

There are many classes that inherits "DataPacket", and thus when I receive a JSON-string from wherever, I need to be able to deserialize the SubPacket into the correct sub-class.

This worked fine before I switched to Json.NET (when I was using DataContractJsonSerializer), but after the switch I havent really been able to deserialize data coming from the Android device.

I suspect it has to do with the fact that I do not send the "qualified type name" from JAVA, and I dont want to do that either. Its OK to send the name, for example:

"$type":"my.namespace.classname"

but its not OK to send all the .NET-related bloated mess that is the "qualified type name".

Right now I am getting a JsonSerializationException. This is a simplified version of the JSON:

```
{
   "SubPacket":{
      "$type":"my.namespace.myClass",
      "HardwareId":"a5af9321038c38dc"
   },
}
```

And even though the class exist on the .NET-side, it fails to deserialize it with the following error:

> {Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Type specified in JSON
>   'my.namespace.myClass' was not resolved. Path 'SubPacket.$type', line
>   1, position 138.    at ...

As mentioned, I DO NOT want to write out the entire Assembly string, which is long and weird to hardcode into a JAVA app.

Thanks for any tips and pointers =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom converter and override the ReadJsonmethod like this :

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, ob
{
    TypedObject toReturn = null;

    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
    {
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var json = obj.ToString();
        string readType = obj["type"].ToString();


        switch (readType)
        {
            case "aClass":
                toReturn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AClass>(json);
                break;
            case "my.namespace.myClass";
                toReturn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
                break;
        }
      }
  return toReturn;

}
```

Regards